# C++17 operator==() and operator!=() code fails with C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading, c++20

I've got the following sample code:

```
#include <assert.h>

struct Base
{
    bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const
    {
        return this->equalTo(rhs);
    }
    virtual bool equalTo(const Base& rhs) const = 0;
};
inline bool operator!=(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

struct A : public Base
{
    int value = 0;
    bool operator==(const A& rhs) const
    {
        return (value == rhs.value);
    }
    virtual bool equalTo(const Base& rhs) const
    {
        auto a = dynamic_cast<const A*>(&rhs);
        return (a != nullptr) ? *this == *a : false;
    }
};

class A_1 : public A
{
    virtual bool equalTo(const Base& rhs) const
    {
        auto a_1 = dynamic_cast<const A_1*>(&rhs);
        return (a_1 != nullptr) ? *this == *a_1 : false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A_1 a_1;
    a_1.value = 1;

    // Make sure different types aren't equal
    A a;
    a.value = 1;
    assert(a_1 != a);
}
```

When I compile with C++17, everything is fine (no *assert*, as desired).  Building the same code with C++20 causes the *assert* to fire.

How can I get this existing code to work when compiling with C++20?  If I crank up the warnings, with C++20, I get `'operator !=': unreferenced inline function has been removed`; I suspect this is all somehow related to `operator<=>()`.

Is this really a known/desired breaking change from C++17 to C++20?

Comment: Just remove `A`'s `operator==`.

Comment: @JackBrown C++20 can synthesize `operator!=()` from `operator==()`, so your `inline operator!=()` is bypassed (add a print in it to see), and it just goes straight to `A`'s `operator==()`

Comment: @康桓瑋 It isn't that simple. `A::equal_to` uses that operator. Removing it can result in infinite recursion.

Comment: @JackBrown Arguably, your code was already broken in C++17. Try `assert(!(a_1 == a));` C++20 just revealed the existing bug.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm. I don't see any infinite recursion. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5W9bref9s).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Reverse the comparison to `assert(a_1 != a);`.

Answer (score 10):

In C++17, the line

```cpp
assert(a_1 != a);
```

Invokes `operator!=(const Base&, const Base&)`, because of course, it's the only candidate. That then invokes `a_1->equalTo(a)`, which tries to downcast `a` to an `A_1`, which in your logic gives you false. So `a_1 != a` evaluates as `true`.

---

In C++20, we now additionally consider rewritten candidates in terms of `==`. So now we have three candidates:

1. `Base::operator==(const Base&) const` (rewritten)
2. `A::operator==(const A&) const` (rewritten)
3. `bool operator!=(const Base&, const Base&)`

Of these, (2) is the best candidate, since it's a better match for the two parameters. So `a_1 != a` evaluates as `!((const A&)a_1 == a)`, which gives you  a different answer.

---

However, your operators are fundamentally broken. Even in C++17, we had the scenario that `a_1 != a` evaluates as `true` while `a != a_1` evaluates as `false`. This is basically the inherent problem of trying to do dynamic equality like this: `this->equalTo(rhs)` and `rhs.equalTo(*this)` might actually do *different things*. So this issue is less of a C++20 comparisons issue and more of a fundamental design issue.