# operator==() code compiles w/C++17 but not C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, spaceship-operator

This code snippet

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Base { };
template<typename T>
inline bool operator==(const T&, const Base&)
{
    return true;
}
template<typename T>
inline bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const Base& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

struct A : public Base
{
    bool operator==(const A&) const { return true; }
};

struct A_1 final : public A { };

int main()
{
    const A a;
    const A_1 a_1;
    if (a_1 != a) {}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiles without errors in C++17 (Visual Studio 2022).
(See [C++17 operator==() and operator!=() code fails with C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945406/c17-operator-and-operator-code-fails-with-c20) for a more detailed example; note in that case the code *compiles*.)

Trying to build the same code with C++20 generates three compiler errors:

```
error C2666: 'operator !=': 3 overloads have similar conversions
message : could be 'bool A::operator ==(const A &) const' [rewritten expression '!(x == y)']
message : or 'bool A::operator ==(const A &) const' [synthesized expression '!(y == x)']
message : or       'bool operator !=<A_1>(const T &,const Base &)'
```

Yes, I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945607/17396741) that C++20 will synthesize `operator!=` and the like ... but shouldn't existing C++17 code still compile with C++20? How can I fix things so that the **same** code compiles with both C++17 and C++20 **and** generates identical results?

Making changes to derived class could be difficult as that code could be elsewhere (this is actually library code); it would be *much* preferred to make changes to `Base`.

Comment: c++20 generates `operator !=` from `operator ==` if not present. So provide all `operator !=` too.

Comment: *"but shouldn't existing C++17 code still compile with C++20"* - Nope. C++20 introduced operand reordering. That was a known potentially breaking change.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question [C++17 operator==() and operator!=() code fails with C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945406/c17-operator-and-operator-code-fails-with-c20)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo "... note in that case the code *compiles*."

Comment: The code is slightly different, but the question is the same, I think.

Comment: @CrisLuengo case (a) code compiles, gives different results at run-time; case (b) (here), code doesn't even compile, no run-time results even exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is because *all* of the functions are now candidate, and before they weren't.

This means that suddently, the `operator==` in `A` is a candidate for `a_1 != a`. The compiler is now allowed to invert the arguments, change `a == b` to `!(a != b)` and vice versa, and even change the order to `b == a`.

The code result in an ambiguous call since `bool operator==(const A&);` in `A` supports `a_1 != a`, by inverting the operation to `!(a_1 == a)` and changing parameter order to finally have `!(a == a_1)` which is a candidate.

There are multiple solution to this.

One is to simply make one candidate better by inheriting the function:

```
struct A_1 final : public A { using A::operator==; };
```

The other would be to restraint the operator to work only with `A`:

```
struct A : public Base
{
    friend bool operator==(std::same_as<A> auto const&, std::same_as<A> auto const&) { return true; }
};
```

Another solution not requirering changing `A` or `A_1` would be to add an overload that is always an ideal candidate inside `Base` as a friend function.

The whole code becomes this in C++20:

```
struct Base {
    friend bool operator==(std::derived_from<Base> auto const&, std::derived_from<Base> auto const&) { return true; }
};

struct A : Base {};
struct A_1 final : A {};
```

You can remove the template function in the global namespace, and you can also remove the function in the derived classes too.

You are not required to remove the function in `A`, but it won't be call and the resulting code will be quite surprising still.

---

However, note that your code was broken before.

This is the compiler output for code using the `operator==` in C++17:

```
int main()
{
    const A a;
    const A_1 a_1;
    if (!(a_1 == a)) {}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:26:15: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const A_1' and 'const A')
   26 |     if (!(a_1 == a)) {}
      |           ~~~ ^~ ~
      |           |      |
      |           |      const A
      |           const A_1
<source>:17:10: note: candidate: 'bool A::operator==(const A&) const'
   17 |     bool operator==(const A&) const { return true; }
      |          ^~~~~~~~
<source>:5:13: note: candidate: 'bool operator==(const T&, const Base&) [with T = A_1]'
    5 | inline bool operator==(const T&, const Base&)
      |             ^~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

C++20 will just accept less code that has a surprising behaviour.

Comment: It would be ideal to do something at the level of `Base` so that I don't have to rummage through all the derived classes ... it might be difficult to even *find* all of them.

Comment: No warning from Visual Studio 2022 :-(

Comment: @JackBrown does my solution with `std::same_as` work for you? It does not require changes in the derived classes.

Comment: You shown changing `A`, not `Base`.

Comment: @JackBrown the compiler is not required to warn code that has extremely surprising code, such as a code that behave differently between `a != b` and `!(a == b)`. GCC won't warn too. However it would not pass code review if I had to review it.

Comment: I'm guessing there is **a lot** of legacy code like that! :-)

Comment: The `same_as` approach in this answer is promising. If you give it a try and it works, I would be interested in possible additional feedback you would have beyond accepting the answer.

Comment: @spectras I'd prefer to not change derived classes (and, as I mentioned, it might not even be *possible* to change them all).

Comment: @JackBrown I added a solution that does not requires change to either `A` or `A_1`, and requires changes only in `Base`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot excellent! I will give that a try; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[It's fine](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94e14b03213866ae) if you remove `A::operator==`.

There's really no point to `A::operator==`, as the template is saying that *everything* is equal to a `Base`.

> but shouldn't existing C++17 code still compile with C++20?

The committee works hard to minimise breaking changes, but they don't promise there will be *none*. In this case it was felt that having `==` be an equivalence relation was more important than maintaining existing behaviour. As the linked question notes, polymorphic equality testing is often a source of bugs.

Comment: It's existing code ... and pared down to a [mcve] for SO.  The problem, for the purposes of this question, is existing code compiles with C++17 but not C++20.

Comment: @JackBrown yes, because C++20 has breaking changes from C++17. No-one promised there were none

Answer (score 0):

C++ extends overload resolution for relational operator to include swapped arguments, which is in the diagnostic message:

- GCC marks the candidate "(reversed)" and
- Clang mentions (with reversed parameter order)

So you need fewer operators. In fact, you could consider overloading / defaulting the three-way comparison operator (`<=>`) instead.